# Linux script for which needs to input password automatically and runs background (No expect and send)

Tags: linux, shell, passwords

I am writing a script which is intended to run every day. Script also consists of a command where I need to input my password lets say abcd every time it execute. Is there any way that I can input password automatically when it ask for "Password:" 
Thanks

Comment: why did you tag with expect if you don't want to use it?

Comment: does this work with that command: `echo "my password" | ./some/command`

Answer (score 1):

Actually it depends on the structure of your script. 2 alternatives on my mind;

Most of the (commonly-used) CLI executables has its own parameter set to provide password / user / credentials. Let me show MySQL for example;

```
shell> mysql --host=localhost --user=myname --password=password mydb
```

If commands you're using are not appropriate to do that; you can consider using "expect" as follows;

```
set password 123
spawn ssh "root@192.168.1.1"
expect "Password:"
send "$password\r";
interact
```

See [that link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

use `xdotool` If not installed then first install this tool in your system using CLI as

```
apt-get install xdotool
```

here is the simple usage

```
xdotool key Ctrl+Alt+t  # for opening termianl
xdotool key Ctrl+Super+Up #super
xdotool type "su" #typing su for root user
xdotool key KP_Enter #pressing enter key
```

check your keyboard short cut compatibilities. I hope helps.